# How do I get phpstorm to indent consistent with existing file indentation

Tags: phpstorm, auto-indent

I use tabs for indentation but the shop I work for uses four spaces, two spaces and tabs inconsistently (but consistently within each file) Is there a way to get phpstorm to indent per the existing code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. Currently PhpStorm supports **single** code style for the **whole project**.

You may be interested in these tickets (to vote/watch/etc):

- [IDEA 69685: Configure Code Style per Scope](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69685) (different style per scope)
- [IDEA-87499: Add editorconfig support](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87499) (different settings per folder/file, via `.editorconfig` files)